# Strongest cipher suite in apache 2.4

Tags: tls, apache, ciphers

I am trying to use only the strongest ciper suite available, from the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html) I tried:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
```

But the browser says that it is obsolete:

[image]

What is the strongest one available at the moment?

Comment: Read the documents on [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/), and [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/). there is no 1 awnser for your question.

ssllabs even has a test tool to check your server with what ciphers are available and how 'secure' those are. (and why)

Comment: From the Chrome docs: [*To avoid this message, use TLS 1.2 and prioritize an ECDHE cipher suite with AES_128_GCM or CHACHA20_POLY1305. Most servers will wish to negotiate TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.*](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls#TOC-Cipher-Suites)

Answer (score 2):

THE strongest is perhaps not well determined. But Chrome wants to see something like TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, i.e. the cipher suite has to use DHE or ECDHE and AES in Galois Counter Mode.

Alternatively you can use CHACHA20_POLY1305 as the symmetric algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

IETF recommends the cipher suites

- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

in [RFC-7525 section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7525#section-4.2) as of May 2015, which I would say are a good choice.

However, the EC variants almost always use the NIST curves (secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1) which are subject to speculations as described [here](http://krakenrider.blogspot.de/2015/11/a-fail.html).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the strongest available cipher suite is not determined by Apache Httpd; it is dependent on the version of openssl (or any other ssl implementation) or your operating system. There are still operating systems coming with "oldstable" openssl-0.9.8 :-(

Comment: True in general, but OP's Chrome screenshot shows TLS1.2 which can only happen for OpenSSL 1.0.1 and up -- and all of those include AESGCM (though not CHACHA/POLY) and ECDHE. Although RedHat (and CentOS etc) *packages* of OpenSSL until about a year ago disabled all ECC including ECDHE. ECDHE must *also* be enabled by by the app level (httpd) setting parameters, but to my understanding 2.4 does have this.